# SQL Developer tab issue

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

So dumb question here, but its driving me insane!:

In SQL developer I often accidentally drag and drop opened 'tabs' from time to time and this then adds it to a different part of the screen so you can see multiple tabs open at once. Great if you do it on purpose, not so easy to undo if by accident.

When i try to 'grab' the 'tab' and place it back where it was it doesn't let me and just drops the tab to a different part of the screen and rearranges everything else in the process.

I currently have to close the tab, find whatever i was viewing again, and open it when my other tab list is open. Hopefully that all makes sense :)

So is there not an easy way to just put the tab back in the previous pane?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've actually had this question for months now, and ironically the same day I posted this question i accidentally stumbled upon the answer. You grab the tab, drag it over the active file in another pane you wish to add it too, and when the full square shows(centered) over the active tab you drop it.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to place all of the tabs back into the same window is to right click on any tab and select the "Collapse Tab Groups" option (see image below). This will put all of the tabs back into the same window.

However if you wish to reorder the tabs within the same window you must use the way that @TheJavaBeast said by dragging it to the center.

Just wanted to add this for more information!

[image: Collapse All Tabs]